# Check first 10 entries for NaN in column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am busy with Jupyter notebook and I need to check the first 10 entries for NaN in my Dataframe

The Code that I tried to check the first 10 entries for NaN is as follow

```
print("\nCount NaN in first 10 entries\n",article_read.sample(10).isnull().sum())#Count NaN in first 10 entries
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use: `article_read.head(10).isna().sum()`

Comment: @Erfan thanks man, I did not find the "How to slice a Pandas Data Frame by position? " post seems simular but your solution worked!

Comment: It's not exactly the same solution, but your problem was that you didn't select the first 10 rows correctly, and that part is explained in the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked:

```
article_read.head(10).isna().sum()
```